# Deserializer Json with Gson in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse data from Json with GSon in java I have this json

```
    {
      "time": 3.251,
      "about_us": {
        "dc:identifier": "some string",
        "dc:title": "some string",
        "dc:contributor": [
          "1",
          "2"
        ],
        "dc:hasversion": "some string"
      },
      "results": {
        "ocw": [
          {
            "title": "some string",
            "url": "some string",
            "language": "some string",
            "university_name": "some string",
            "university_url": "some string",
            "description": "",
            "uri": "some string5",
            "similar": "some string",
            "resourceType": "OCW",
            "relatedoers": [

                    ]
          }
        ],
        "otheroer": [

        ]
      }
    }
```

I only need to get the `"ocw"` field, I am confused how to do this.
I created corresponding java classes for the json objects and use @SerializedName annotations to specify the field name to grab for each data member.

The classes are as follows.

Results

Ocw

Comment: What research have you found on this so far or what code you have tried? There should be lots of examples for this out there.

Comment: "ocw" isn't a field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this json stored in some `jsonString`:

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("results").getAsJsonArray("ocw").get(0);
    MyObject object = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonElement, MyObject.class);
```

MyObject should reflect this part:

```
        "title": "some string",
        "url": "some string",
        "language": "some string",
        "university_name": "some string",
        "university_url": "some string",
        "description": "",
        "uri": "some string5",
        "similar": "some string",
        "resourceType": "OCW",
        "relatedoers": [

                ]
```